# Recording of events by grabbed windows in x11

Tags: c, keyboard, window, x11, xcb

Suppose KeyPress events are being recorded by my program. Now, I create a simple window, child of the root window, and after mapping it, will grab keyboard to it using XGrabKeyboard(). Now, my question is, the next key press event that will be recorded by my program, will be recorded from the grabbed window or all windows.

That's because, I tried it and found that though I grabbed the keyboard for a particular window, events were still recorded globally, irrespective of grabbing.

So is there a way to obtain key-press events only from the grabbed window ?

Comment: are you sure of you ? seems very strange the event is not only sent to the grabbed window and its descendants

Comment: Ya what I meant was: I grabbed keyboard to the new window. Then clicked the mouse pointer to a the terminal window (which is not grabbed). Now when I pressed any key, it still printed the keycode in the terminal, which as per my understanding, shouln't have printed, as mouse pointer is clicked to terminal window and not the grabbed window.

Comment: what value you used for owner_event ? ( *If owner_events is False, all generated key events are reported with respect to grab_window. If owner_events is True and if a generated key event would normally be reported to this client, it is reported normally; otherwise, the event is reported with respect to the grab_window.*). But if I well understand the focus moved to the terminal out of your application no ? so you received the event _FocusOut_

Comment: I have set owner_events to True

Comment: But when you click on the terminal windows you go out of your application no ? and you are warn when the focus go in/out

Comment: Ok.. one clarification. Does mouse-pointer click change the grabbing status, or will the grab still lie with the grabbed window itself ?

Comment: You said the terminal got the event no ? so you have the answer :-)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification !